# Error in running sample android application on an emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android development.

I created the sample hello world and try to run it on a emulated nexus 7 system.

I am using android studio 1.8.14.

When I run the application, I am getting this message in andoid studio:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: test_nexus_7 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\m\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.m.myapplication
Installing com.example.m.myapplication
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.m.myapplication"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a known bug. Does this solve your issue?

"2 Error: could not access the package manager. Is the system running?

You may have gotten this error while attempting to run an Android application on an emulator or device using Android Studio. The most common cause of this error is simple: You have to manually unlock your Android Virtual Device by swiping the “lock” icon on the screen. Security measures prevent the emulator from letting you connect the debugger before doing this."

Read more at http://www.airpair.com/android/bugs-annoying-android-developers#1vMSj7GfowjRvMLG.99

Other suggestions: wait for the emulator to fully start up, which could take longer than you expected, or try debugging on an Android device, which is faster and has access to native functionality, rather than in an emulator.